# Need to create a folder(and a file inside it) using C# inside Azure DevOps repository - be it Git or TFVC

Tags: c#, azure-devops

From Azure DevOps portal, I can manually add file/ folder into repository irrespective of the fact that source code is cloned or not - [Image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8F69.png).

However, I want to programmatically create a folder and a file inside that folder within a Repository from c# code in my ASP .NET core application.

Is there a Azure DevOps service REST API or any other way to do that? I'll use BASIC authentication through PAT token only.

Note : I'm restricted to clone the source code at local repository.

Early reply is really appreciated.

I tried HttpClient, GitHttpClient and LibGit2Sharp but failed.

Comment: Which code did you try and which error did you get?

Comment: I couldn't find anything to accomplish my requirements

Comment: Early response is  highly appreciated

Comment: Anyone there to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps in your C# code

1. call GetRef REST [https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/git/repositories/{2}/refs{3}](https://dev.azure.com/%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7B2%7D/refs%7B3%7D)
   this should return the object of your repository branch which you can use to push your changes
2. Next, call Push REST API to create folder or file into your repository
   [https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/git/repositories/{2}/pushes{3}](https://dev.azure.com/%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7B2%7D/pushes%7B3%7D)

   ```
              var changes = new List<ChangeToAdd>();
               //Add Files

               //pnp_structure.yml
               var jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(@"./static-files/somejsonfile.json");

               ChangeToAdd changeJson = new ChangeToAdd()
               {
                   changeType = "add",
                   item = new ItemBase() { path = string.Concat(path, "/[your-folder-name]/somejsonfile.json") },
                   newContent = new Newcontent()
                   {
                       contentType = "rawtext",
                       content = jsonContent
                   }
               };
               changes.Add(changeJson);


               CommitToAdd commit = new CommitToAdd();
               commit.comment = "commit from code";
               commit.changes = changes.ToArray();

               var content = new List<CommitToAdd>() { commit };
               var request = new
               {
                   refUpdates = refs,
                   commits = content
               };

        var personalaccesstoken = _configuration["azure-devOps-configuration-token"];

       var authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken)));

       _logger.LogInformation($"[HTTP REQUEST] make a http call with uri: {uri} ");

        //here I making http client call 
        // https://dev.azure.com/{orgnizationName}/{projectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes{?api-version}
       var result = _httpClient.SendHttpWebRequest(uri, method, data, authorization);
   ```